# How to use "head" in a script with "pipefail" enabled?

Tags: bash, error-handling, pipe

Imagine a call like this:

```
./generator.sh | head -1
```

This script is embedded in a larger context and it might happen that parts of it fail due to wrong configuration, etc. In such a case we do not want to continue with the script, so we set the `pipefail` option. But now we obviosuly face the problem that when `head` closes the receiving end, generator will fail. How can we mitigate the problem?

Is there a way to tell `head` to keep going, but to discard the input (this would be ideal, as we do not even want the early-exit semantics here).

I know that we can just disable/reenable `pipefail` for that piece, but I wonder if there is a shorter option.

Comment: Insert `sponge |`  before `head`?

Comment: That is a very interesting solution. I do not know if I want to demand moreutils on all hosts, but a very interesting solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ? Is there a way to tell head to keep going, but to discard the input (this would be ideal, as we do not even want the early-exit semantics here).

There is `sed`: delete all except first line:

```
sed '1!d'
```

Comment: @choeger what do you mean by "short and pregnant"?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could also do this, which captures the full output of generator.sh, before calling head

```
IT=$(./generator.sh)
echo "$IT" | head -1
```